# Как отловить Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index

Tags: php, mysql

Как отловить эту ошибку? Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index

Чтобы она не выводилась на экран, а была допустим передана в переменную $error = "ERROR";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `try/catch` подробнее тут: [PHP исключения](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php).

Answer (score 0):

Или попробуйте это:

> ```
>  error_reporting(); 
>  error_reporting(0);
>  error_reporting(7);
>  error_reporting(8);
> ```